# Remote SSH connection failed

Tags: visual-studio-code

It shows *Failed to connect to the remote extension host server (Error: Handler already set!)*.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfXRO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved with the following 2 steps:

1. delete the existing VScode's workspaces in the storage
2. restart VScode

For macOS users, the workspaces are located "/Users/{your-user-name}/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/".